# active admin global sidebar , like wordpress

Tags: activeadmin

As per AcitveAdmin [Docs](https://www.activeadmin.info/7-sidebars.html) , it is possible to add a sidebar per *resource*.

but what I would like to achieve is having something like wordpress sidebar that shows everything at the sidebar , just like the navbar links (which show the selected resource) but as a sidebar.

is it possible to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, override [ActiveAdmin::Views::Pages::Base#build_sidebar](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/9d0557ad05ece0da59a4df2c61468479093686a1/lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb#L129).  It might be easier, however, to register the same sidebar in every resource definition.